# The compiler can not find the resource file

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, resources

If I move the resource file to the resource folder, it will not be found.
However, when the resource file is placed in the main folder, it is recognized.
I did not understand why. Please help me.
Why do not they recognize it when they're in a resource folder?

main file
ApplicationContextExam01.java

```
package kr.or.connect.diexam01;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class ApplicationContextExam01 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml");
    System.out.println("init!!");

    UserBean userBean = (UserBean)ac.getBean("userBean");
    userBean.setName("sakura");
    System.out.println(userBean.getName());
  }
}
```

resource file
applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <bean id="userBean" class="kr.or.connect.diexam01.UserBean"></bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)   .....
Etc

Comment: What is the 'main' folder and what is the 'resource' folder. Since for Maven based project the resource folder is located under main right next to the src folder?

Answer (score 0):

Your resource file should be placed in the default package that is your "src" folder. and when starting your context you just call your file by
`ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");`